# Dynamics CRM Custom Web Authentication

Tags: authentication, dynamics-crm

We have a project in which the customer needs the crm to be authenticated using a custom web form. I do not want to use the default IDF provided by crm. Is there a way we can pass the user name and password to crm authentication dialog? Or any suggested approach?

Answer (score 1):

There is no supported ways of doing that, and there is no SDK/API that is available to pre-authenticate a user against a IFD deployed CRM Server.

The only way that I can think of is webpage-scraping, and posting to it, but I have never done that...